# Spectral norm of secondary block diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Suppose there is a matrix $A$, and a symmetric matrix $B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & A \\ A^{\top} & 0\end{bmatrix}$. Can we prove the following:
$$\Vert B \Vert = \Vert A \Vert$$
where $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is the spectral norm of a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The nontrivial eigenvalues of $B$ are $\pm$ the singular values of $A$, so you have to identity $\|A\|$ with the largest singular value of $A$, somehow.

The claim that the eigenvalues of $B$ are $\pm$ the singular values of $A$ follows from the SVD decomposition $A=P\Lambda Q^T$ where $\Lambda$ is "diagonal" and $P$ and $Q$ orthogonal.  We have $$
B = \begin{pmatrix}0&A\\A^T&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&P\Lambda  Q^T\\Q\Lambda^T P^T&0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}P&0\\0&Q\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&\Lambda\\\Lambda^T&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}P^T&0\\0&Q^T\end{pmatrix}$$ so the spectrum of $B$ is the same as that of $L=\begin{pmatrix}0&\Lambda\\\Lambda^T&0\end{pmatrix}$.  Permuting the rows and columns of $L$ brings it into block diagonal form, where the $i$th $2\times2$ diagonal block is $\pmatrix{0&\lambda_i\\\lambda_i&0}$, whose characteristic polynomial is $z^2-\lambda_i^2$ and spectrum therefore $\{\pm\lambda_i\}$.  (There are also possibly $1\times1$ diagonal "blocks" of $0$, when $A$ and $\Lambda$ are rectangular: these contribute extra copies of $0$ to the spectrum of $B$.  There do not affect the spectral norm of $B$.)

Alternatively, you could start with the identity $B^2 = \pmatrix{AA^T&0\\0&A^TA},$ and see that the spectrum of $B^2$ is the union of the squares of the singular values of $A$, together with $|r-c|$ copies of $0$, where $A$ has $r$ rows and $c$ columns.

Comment: Can you provide a formal proof for that? Thanks!

Comment: Of which part?  The ratio $\|Ax\|_2/\|x\|_2$ is maximized when $x$ is a singular vector of $A$.

Comment: Why the eigenvalues of $B$ are $\pm$ the singular values of $A$

Comment: @Tom I have edited my answer accordingly